# javascript out update onchange

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the javascript below to automatically update the input field (centimeters) below when a user select there height and inches. It should auto calculate the centimeters, and its not working.

```
<script type=​"text/​javascript">​
updateHeights:function(type){
    if(type=='english'){
        var feet=parseInt($F('feet'));
        var inches=parseInt($F('inches'));
        var cm=((feet*12+inches)*2.54).round();
        $('centimeters').value=(feet?cm:'');
        } 
        else 
        {
        var cm=parseInt($F('centimeters'))||183;
    if(cm>241||cm<91)cm=183;
        var inches_total=(cm*0.3937).round();
        var feet=(inches_total/12).floor();
        var inches=inches_total%12;
        $('feet').value=feet;
        $('inches').value=inches;
        $('centimeters').value=cm;
    }
}
</script>

<label>Height:</label>
<select id="feet" name="add[feet]" onchange="Profile.updateHeights('english')">
    <option value="">—</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>ft.&nbsp;&nbsp;
<select id="inches" name="add[inch]" onchange="Profile.updateHeights('english')">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
</select>in. or&nbsp;
<input id="centimeters" type="text" name="centimeters" maxlength="3" value="178" onchange="Profile.updateHeights('metric')" style="width: 30px;" />
&nbsp;centimeters
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Is your code even being executed? What part doesn't work?

Comment: Is the `$F()` function defined somewhere? Can we assume that your `updateHeights : function() ...` is just one property of a `Profile` object that is not shown? Because as posted that is not valid syntax and we can't tell what if anything is wrong with that object's definition. Also, why have you hard-coded _my_ height (183cm)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this is just an excerpt from your entire code, Profile is a legitimate class name, and $F is defined somewhere, you're missing a few things.

First off, you're selecting by ID, so you need to include the # sign in your selectors.
Second, you're trying to parse an object as an integer. You need to use `parseInt($("#feet").val())` to select the value contained in the input. Likewise, to set a value, you're going to want to use `$("#centimeters").val(cm);`